# List Splitting by Even Position

Tags: list-manipulation

How to select only even elements of a list, position-wise.

```
l = {1, 4, 5, 4, 1}
(* f[l] returns *)
(* Out: {4,4} *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = Array[a, 11];
```

If you want the even positions

```
list[[2 ;; ;; 2]]

(* {a[2], a[4], a[6], a[8], a[10]} *)
```

or

```
Last /@ Partition[list, 2]

(* {a[2], a[4], a[6], a[8], a[10]} *)
```

Comment: Good, now what about Odd members on their own? I was ONE-off.

Comment: AHA, [[1 ;; ;; 2]] never mind.

Answer (score 4):

`Part` has a step specification:

```
l[[2;;-1;;2]]
```